# Remote Development Extensions

Tags: github, repository, remote-access, git-remote

I have downloaded the remote repositories extensions for VS code. I tend to work on a lot of computers and want to have a setup of VS code either portable if I can or if not at least remote so I can just connect to my repository, do some work and then file a push action.

I've connected and added projects I want to work on in my workspace however I can't add any files. It was my understanding that working "remote" would allow me to stage changes and such as if they were local and then push on save or commit but whenever I try to add a file to the repository it says it can't resolve.

This could be my inexperience with git control. But is there something additional I need to do to have source control within the remote container?

I tried git init but there isn't a local clone. I've reviewed documentation as much as I can and don't see anything indicating you can't add files.